# How to fix Excel assuming dates are continuous

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

I'm setting up a work planner/diary of sorts for use of employees to track their tasks over a month and senior employees to track what they are doing on a given day of the week

There is one 'Overview' sheet with all the employees on and (theoretically) the tasks they are on with on that day. It should pull information from an employees individual sheet and display it on the overview page. This means it needs to automatically update the information every day.

The problem I'm having with the formula I'm using is that Excel seems to assume that the dates on the overview page are continuous and not all the same. So instead of having;

```
Employee A
9th Feb - Task - Task - Task

Employee B
9th Feb - Task - Task - Task
```

It shows;

```
Employee A
9th Feb - Task - Task - Task

Employee B
10th Feb - Task - Task - Task
```

I've attached an example spreadsheet for you to peruse. Is it an issue with the formulae that is causing this?

Thanks.

These are the formulae I'm using to get excel to check the date and automatically update information

For Date;

```
=IF(INDEX('Employee 1'!A:A,MATCH(TODAY(),'Employee 1'!A:A,0)+ROW()-2)=0,"",INDEX('Employee 1'!A:A,MATCH(TODAY(),'Employee 1'!A:A,0)+ROW()-2))
```

For Tasks;

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('Employee 1'!$C:$C,MATCH($A2,'Employee 1'!$A:$A,0)+ROW()-2),"")
```

Comment: might want to check the ROW()-2 function. if you copy this down, it will increase the function result by the number of rows down you copy that formula. highlight the entire row_num argument in the INDEX function then press F9. this will tell you which row number the function is asking to return. is it performing as expected for ALL employees? main reason i ask is we do not know what your 'Employee 1' worksheet looks like.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond.

It is sort of working as expecting as it is returning the information related to those dates. The issue is that it is listing the dates in continuous order on the front page of the workbook instead of returning the same date for each individual employee.

So Employee 1 is showing all of the current days tasks (correct)
Employee 2 is showing tomorrow's tasks (wrong day)
Employee 3 is showing the day after etc etc.

Comment: the only component that looks off is your use of ROW(). as you copy the formula down, this will increase by the number of rows. assuming your 'Employee 1' tab has each row as the date, the use of ROW() will skip down the list. again, without knowing what your 'Employee 1' table looks like, i can only assume row row_num formula is returning the row that is ROW() number of rows below your desired result. using F9 on each of your row_num arguments for ALL employees will help discern this.